# Can I use a jar, compiled in Java 7 as a dependency in a project that is compiled against Java 6?

Tags: java, maven, jvm

Can I use a jar, compiled in Java 7 as a dependency in a project that is compiled for compatibility with Java 6? I do not have the source code of the dependency. I have the compiled jar as a maven dependency.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? What was the result.

Comment: Yes you can, if you cross compile to Java 1.6 i.e. `source=1.7 target=1.6` but be aware that you can not use sort of Java standard library classes available starting from 1.7 or you will have ClassNotFound exceptions.

Comment: `I do not have the source code of the dependency.` - you can try to unzip the jar and de-compile with some de-compiler like JD

Comment: The simple question is: Does the dependency use Java 7 specific things? If yes you can't use if not you can use it...

Comment: @Ben Yes I tried doing that and it runs for the methods I'm calling, for now. Consider this scenario. Say, there is a method in Java 6,  and in Java 7 there is an overriden implementation of the same method. The overriden method in Java 7 uses features of Java 7. Now, the code will compile with a Java 6 compiler, alright, as the compiler can see the method, but override happens in runtime. So,my method call may fail in runtime. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @VictorGubin I'm afraid, de-compiling is not an option in this case.

Comment: @VictorGubin *if you cross compile to Java 1.6 i.e. source=1.7 target=1.6* Ummm, [how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27070163/2970947)

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch Using Eclipse Java compiler instead of javac In any case - in most cases - 1.7+ code  using new platform library, so it is just a time waste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use a jar, compiled in Java 7 as a dependency in a project that is compiled for compatibility with Java 6?

Let's unpick this:

- You have a project that is compiled so that will run on a Java 6 JRE.  (Lets suppose that you only use Java 6 APIs in that project.)  The .class files for this project *must* have a classfile format major version less or equal to 50 ... otherwise a Java 6 JRE won't be able to load them.
- Then you have a dependency that is "compiled in Java 7".  That could mean one of two things:

  1. It could have been compiled using a Java 7 tool chain but with a target version of Java 6.
  2. It could have been compiled using a Java 7 tool chain for Java 7.

In both subcases above above, you *should* be able to use the dependency in your Java 6 project if you run the project on a Java 7 JRE<sup>1</sup>.  A Java 7 JRE can load and run classfiles compiled for Java 6.  In one of the subcases, you will be loading classes with two (or more) class version numbers.  But that is OK.

On the other hand, if you try to run the code on a Java 6 JRE, then:

- Subcase 1 will work *provided that* the Java 7 dependency doesn't make use of any Java 7 (or later) APIs; i.e. it only uses Java standard classes, methods, etc that were present in Java 6 or earlier.
- Subcase 2 will not work.  The Java 6 JRE won't be able to load the dependency.  Indeed, if the dependency is static (i.e. the project source code has compile time dependencies on the APIs of the dependent), then the project code won't build ... because the Java 6 compiler should refuse to read the dependency's newer version classfiles.

---

The most advisable approach is to migrate your project and your execution platform to Java 7.  Or better still to Java 8 or Java 11, since Java 7 is EOL'd

If you can't do that, the next best thing would be to avoid using the Java 7 dependency ... until you can upgrade.

If you have customers who insist they you continue to support Java 6, then they are impeding your ability to progress your product line.  They should be charged a premium for that.

If you have decided to avoid upgrading your Java platform for internal reasons, this decision is accumulating technical debt ... that your organization will need to "pay down" that debt in the long term.

---

<sup>1 - .... or JDK.  A JDK is equivalent to a JRE for the purposes of running code.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In your case you actually ask if there is Forward Compatibility between Java 6 and Java 7. Generally speaking Java does not support Forward Compatibility as the 1.7 JVM cannot run code compiled with 1.6. This happens mainly because the version of 1.7 compiled Java bytecode is not known by the older version (1.6).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to confirm compatibility the other way. I have a dependency, that is compiled in Java 7 and I'm using it in a project that I am compiling for target=1.6. I have some legacy applications, that, unfortunately, cannot be upgraded to use JRE 7, right away. So, I want to make sure, if my jar, compiled in v6, which in turn uses a dependency, compiled in v7, is going to run using JRE 6 or not.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I just updated the answer.