# Can't Compile Java 11 Code With Source Options

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to test cross compilation between modules. I have a module which uses java 1.8 and another module uses Java 11. I am trying to use Java 11 module as dependency on Java 1.8 project. When I try to compile Java 11 module, maven shows an error.

## MAIN MODULE

```
<project>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.berkin</groupId>
                <artifactId>java</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

## SECONDARY MODULE NAMED JAVA

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.berkin</groupId>
    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## CODE ON SECONDARY MODULE

```
public class Test {
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(" ".isEmpty()); //true
    }
}
```

In theory I should able to compile secondary module with java 11 compiler and use it in min Java 8 JRE. Thus I can also use it in Java 8 project as a dependency. Where am I missing?

> ERROR

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project java: Fatal error compiling: invalid source release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: *I should able to compile secondary module with java 11 compiler and use it in min Java 8 JRE* Who told you that? Java 8 doesn't even have the module system (that came in Java 9)

Comment: Can you explain the difference between what am I doing here and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551633/can-i-use-a-jar-compiled-in-java-7-as-a-dependency-in-a-project-that-is-compile. Thanks

Comment: The invalid sources release looks like you are not using JDK11 to compile your code apart from that it might be a bad idea to go that way ...the question is: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: It's possible to use lower source and upper target but not vice versa.
So source 11 and target 1.8 in the second module is incorrect

Comment: @Berkin Did you not understand [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555472/2970947)? *you should be able to use the dependency in your Java 6 project if you run the project on a Java 7 JRE* You can use Java 6 in Java 7, or Java 8 in Java 11, not the other way around.

Comment: I think i didnt. Because it said It could have been compiled using a Java 7 tool chain but with a target version of Java 6. Isn't it source 7 target 6? If so, why I can't do the same?

Comment: No. That would be source and target 6 with the 7 compiler; which will also work. You can't have source 7 and target 6, and if you tried you would have discovered that you had it exactly backwards (just like here).

Comment: I have the same thing. I have Java 8 project with compiled Java 8. And I have a dependency with compiled 11 and targeted 8. In this case, I should be able to use.

Comment: Am I confusing between source & target with compiler version? Doesn't source mean compiler version?

Comment: No. The source would also have to be **8**. And that will work. But as I already said, Java 8 does **not** have modules. So you 100% can't use your "secondary module" with a Java 8 JRE.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you look at my last comment. I think I understand

Comment: AFAIK, you need to use `<configuration ><release >11</release ></configuration >` now. I'll see if I can find the blog post I just read about it.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that you cannot use a `source` value that is lower than the `target` value. If you want the code to be compatible with Java 1.8, lower the source to 1.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551633/can-i-use-a-jar-compiled-in-java-7-as-a-dependency-in-a-project-that-is-compile. It is been said that It could have been compiled using a Java 7 tool chain but with a target version of Java 6. Isn't it source 7 target 6?

Answer (score 0):

I get it thanks to @Elliott Frisch

There are several terms;

*Java Compiler* : It is defined by JAVA_HOME or if you override by selecting another Java version for Maven thats it. You can compile Java 6 codes with Java 11 compiler. Because it has backward compatibility.

*Source* : Minimum Java version which you want to use java features. For example, if I want to use lambdas, at least I have to use source 8. If I want to use Java 11 features, I need to set it to 11. **Its all about Java Features that you want to use**

*Target* : Minimum JRE version which can run my features. E.g. if I set Java 8, I need at least JRE 8 to use lambdas. I can't use JRE 7 or lower because they don't know what lambda is.

Also

If java compiler version is 8, it can't compile source 11 classes. Because compiler don't know how to compile Java 11. I failed at the beginning because I had lower than source. When I changed into 11 & 11, I failed again because this time compiler was older(It was Java 8)

Thanks